# Нужно ли тире перед "значит"?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, требуется ли тире перед словом "значит" в таком предложении: "Понять человека (—) значит сочувствовать ему"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, тире здесь необходимо, так как слово ЗНАЧИТ является средством связи между подлежащим и сказуемым. В этом случае перед ним всегда ставится тире. 
Слово ЗНАЧИТ может выполнять функцию простого глагольного сказуемого, и в этом случае тире перед ним не ставится: *Что это значит?*
  Слово ЗНАЧИТ часто бывает вводным словом, и тогда оно выделяется запятыми: Мы не увидимся, значит?

Answer (score 2):

Тире перед "это", "вот","значит" ставится всегда:

http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_172

Например:  Понять – значит простить; Все прошедшее, настоящее, будущее – это мы, а не слепая сила стихий (Горький).

Comment: Если это тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. А если "значит" в сложноподчинённом предложении, будете ставить?

Answer (score 2):

***Если в составе сказуемого есть указательные слова "ЭТО","ВОТ","ЗНАЧИТ" - тире надо ставить перед ними всегда, вне зависимости от того, какой частью речи выражены главные члены предложения.***

- *Например: Париж – это столица    Франции; Понять – значит простить; 

     Все прошедшее, настоящее, будущее –

     это мы, а не слепая сила стихий.*
- К этому правилу есть три примечания.
      Тире между **подлежащим** и **сказуемым**,
      которые выражены  существительными,
      глаголами в неопределенной форме,
      числительными или сочетаниями этих
      частей речи, **НЕ ставится**, если

*1. Перед **сказуемым**, которое выражено существительным, числительным или фразеологическим оборотом, стоит отрицательная частица НЕ:

- Например: Старость не радость*

*2. Перед сказуемым стоит сравнительный союз (КАК, СЛОВНО, БУДТО):

- Например: Закат словно зарево
     пожара.*

*3. Между подлежащим и сказуемым-существительным стоит вводное слово, обстоятельство или дополнение, а также союз или частица:

- Например: Грач, конечно, птица умная
     и самостоятельная, но голоса у него
     нет; Москва теперь порт пяти морей;
     Этот ручей лишь начало реки.*